# Is it appropriate to change the semicolon?

Tags: grammar, meaning

From Sylvia Chalker. (1996). Collins Cobuild English Guides: Linking words. p. 53.

> And please don't say anything until we're there; that is ,if we ever get
> there.

There are many articles describing that semicolons only join two related independent clauses, e.g., ['5 Ways to Use a Semicolon, With Examples'](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/semicolon/),[Semicolon](https://www.niu.edu/writingtutorial/punctuation/semicolon.shtml).

So,is the sentence informal?

Could I rewrite the sentence to

1. And please don't say anything until we're there, that is, if we ever get there.
2. And please don't say anything until we're there – that is, if we ever get there.
3. And please don't say anything until we're there (that is, if we ever get there).?

Are they correct?

Comment: Yes, #2 and #3 are good. But so is a period. The original is quite good.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin And #1 ?

Comment: #1 is not logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; the original sentence would often be considered not merely informal but actually incorrect. That's because the last clause (beginnning with "if") is a dependent clause, and a semicolon should not join a main clause to a dependent clause. (I consider "that is" to be a disjunct, like a sentence adverb or interjection.)

Your three suggestions are all good, because each surrounds the dependent clause with paired punctuation (the first with commas, the second with dashes, and the third with parentheses), which is correct because the clause is nonrestrictive. (The second punctuation mark is omitted in the first and second sentence because it would appear next to the period. And "that is" is correctly surrounded by its own paired commas.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that all three are technically correct, however, the first one may be less suitable (see what I did there? :p)

Because of the double comma, you may read this in two different ways. It's a bit hard to explain with just text, but the 'that is' (or 'however' in my sentence) may be read as though belonging to the first part of the sentence.

Basically you'd read it either
"And please don't say anything until we're there that is, if we ever get there."
or
"And please don't say anything until we're there, that is if we ever get there."